# Send 2 different camera feeds to ffserver from ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, ffserver

I'm currently working in a project where I have to stream 2 webcams streams from a computer to another through a TCP connection, I can stream 1 without problem:

using

ffserver.conf:

```
            HTTPPort 8090
            HTTPBindAddress 0.0.0.0
            MaxClients 40
            MaxBandwidth 30000

            CustomLog -
            NoDaemon

            <Stream status.html>
            Format status
            ACL allow localhost
            ACL allow 192.168.0.0 192.168.255.255
            </Stream>

           #feed for camera 1
           <Feed webcam1.ffm>
           File /tmp/webcam1.ffm
           FileMaxSize 100M
           </Feed>

           #feed for camera 2
           <Feed webcam2.ffm>
           File /tmp/webcam2.ffm
           FileMaxSize 100M
           </Feed>

          #stream for feed 1
          <Stream webcam1.mjpeg>
          Feed webcam1.ffm
          Format mjpeg
          VideoSize 1280x720
          VideoFrameRate 30
          Preroll 0
          NoAudio
          Strict -1
          </Stream>

          #stream for feed2
          <Stream webcam2.mjpeg>
          Feed webcam2.ffm
          Format mjpeg
          VideoSize 1280x720
          VideoFrameRate 30
          Preroll 0
          NoAudio
          Strict -1
          </Stream>
```

command to run ffserver:

```
          ffserver /etc/ffserver.conf
```

command to feed ffserver:

```
         ffmpeg -v 2 -r 20 -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 http://localhost:8090/webcam1.ffm
```

and it works perfect, but when I try to run the other feed:

```
         ffmpeg -v 2 -r 20 -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video1 http://localhost:8090/webcam2.ffm
```

I can see just the second stream and the first one do not work anymore.
some idea?

Comment: Are you sure you're sending both feeds on the good port? Because your config uses port `8090` but you're sending to port `80` in the two command examples. They shouldn't work at all like this, is it a typo?

Comment: sorry i forgot, the command for ffmpeg is

Comment: ffmpeg ..... ....    http://localhost:8090/.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using multiple USB webcams simultaneously may saturate the bus. This seems to be your case since starting the second camera cuts the first one off.

> The situation has improved from when USB1.1 was common. Most even
>   low-end motherboards have multiple USB2/3 controllers, which are
>   entirely independent and can run multiple cameras without concern.
>   USB2 can support multiple cameras at low resolution and framerate.
>   *High framerate high resolution cameras sending uncompressed images may
>   still saturate the bus*

[Source](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/FrequentlyAskedQuestions)

Possible solutions:

1. **Switch to MJPEG input (lower bandwidth use)**

Check the capabilities of your device:

`ffmpeg -f v4l2 -list_formats all -i /dev/video0`

If it supports MJPEG then use it instead of raw video:

`ffplay -f v4l2 -input_format mjpeg -i /dev/video0 ...`

2. **Use a different USB controller for the second camera**

If the motherboard doesn't feature multiple controllers then get a PCI USB card.

Comment: Thanks a lot! you were right! the bus get saturated! i bought a PCI USB card, and now is much better, im actually compressing in mjpeg or h264 :D! master!!!

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Please consider marking the question as solved.